# Write to clipboard content with mime type `text/html`

Tags: go, clipboard, mime-types

How I can to write content to desktop clipboard with type `text/html` in Go?

I want a program (wrote on Go) on a computer, when executing a command, to generate documentation for a specific method in html format and save the documentation to the computer's clipboard with the mime type `text/html`. Everything is there, except for saving to the clipboard with the mime type `text/html`, those packages that I found save only in the format `text/plain`.

Comment: What do you mean by "clipboard"?  Are you building a desktop application of some sort? Or a web app? In either case, update your question with enough details.

Comment: @JonathanHall described in more detail

Comment: You didn't answer my questions with your update at all.

Comment: @JonathanHall I'm creating a cli application that needs to save content of type `text/html` to the clipboard